# Git not found even after installing on Amazon linux 2 OS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, git, docker

I am using the **AWS Python base image** for deploying my project as the docker image for the lambda function. Below is my docker file for installing `git` in the docker image. Commands ran successfully but when I tried to verify git via CLI it wasn't found. Below is my docker file code:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

# Install the function's dependencies using file requirements.txt
# from your project folder.

COPY requirements.txt  .

RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"; \
     yum update -y \
     yum install git -y

# Copy function code
COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

I have used ENTRYPOINT to check via CLI. This is the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html) where the list of base images can be found. When I checked my image I can see that **git** is installed.
[image]

P.S: I want to use base images only.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: "Commands ran successfully but when I tried to verify git via CLI it wasn't found" How exactly did you try to verify `git` was installed via the CLI? The only CLI command you show is an `ls` command for one folder, and without stating what folder you are doing the `ls` in. That alone would not verify if something was installed in the container or not.

Comment: By verify I mean, I ran git command inside the cli and it threw an error saying that `git command was not found`. Yes, it is not installed may be correct or lacking some permissions while installing not sure exactly what because when I do import git inside python it throws an error. But this is how it is installed for `Amazon Linux 2` OS as per multiple blogs. May be you can throw some light on what exactly am I doing wrong here. @MarkB

Comment: The actual error message you are getting: "git command was not found" is a key detail that should have been included in the original question.

Comment: You forgot the `;` after the `yum update` command. `yum install git -y` are all being treated as additional arguments to the first `yum` command, not a second invocation of `yum`.

Comment: I would use `&&` instead of `;`; if one command fails, you likely don't need to bother running any of the subsequent commands in the command line.

Comment: Your image already contains the application code, via the `COPY` directive; do you separately need `git` installed?  I'd also recommend deleting that `ENTRYPOINT` line, since it can cause some surprising behavior (for example, any words beyond the first in a `CMD` list will get ignored, and shell-form `CMD` just won't work).

Comment: I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Dockerfile`, Please look at this `RUN` command:

```
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"; \
     yum update -y \
     yum install git -y
```

See how you have a semicolon after the first command? That semicolon is key to separating each of the commands. The `\` just splits the text up into multiple lines for readability. The `\` doesn't do anything regarding actually separating the commands. When this `RUN` command is interpreted, the `\` characters are going to be stripped out and it is all going to be on one line, like this:

```
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"; yum update -y yum install git -y
```

So the interpreter is only going to see two commands here, a `pip3 install` command, and a `yum update` command. The `yum update` command is getting some extra arguments of `yum install git -y` that you didn't intend to give it, and it appears to be ignoring those, or in any case not failing because of those.

The semicolon is what tells the interpreter "this is the end of this command, the next text starts a new command". So make sure you have a semicolon between each command:

```
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"; \
     yum update -y ; \
     yum install git -y
```

Comment: This didn't work as well.

Comment: Are you saying removing `yum update -y` caused `git` to start working? I find that extremely unlikely. I'm pretty sure it was the missing semicolon, and since you completely removed the command that was missing the semicolon that fixed it.

Comment: I will try with semicolon and will let you know for sure.

Comment: Yeah you were correct. I inserted the semicolon and it fixed everything. Thanks for pointing it out. I will delete my answer.

Comment: Also can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76508986/aws-python-docker-base-image-via-gitlab-pipeline-raises-error ?